# Is it possible to know the space take by files inside a .tar.bz2

Tags: linux, bash, tar, du

I usually use `du -h` (-h for human readable format) to know the space take by my files. 
I have compressed some folders with `.tar.bz2`, but I am not sure if it works well. I mean, if all the files have been properly compressed. I know that it is possible to extract a given file inside the `.tar.bz2`, but I was wondering if 
 there is a way to `du -h` inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
tar -jtvf file-name.tar.bz2
```

If thats not detailed enough, you could use awk to extract the bytes:

```
tar -jtvf asg2.tar.bz2 | awk '{print $3}'
```

And if you want to get the total of the bytes, you could do something like:

```
tar -jtvf asg2.tar.bz2 | awk '{print s+=$3}' | tail -1
```

And finally, to convert it to human-readable format:

```
echo $(tar -jtvf asg2.tar.bz2 | awk '{print s+=$3}' | tail -1) | awk '{foo = $1 / 1024 / 1024 ; print foo "MB" }'
```

Output:

```
0.00749779MB
```

Answer (score 0):

A `tar.bz2` file is a `bzip2`-compression of an ordinary `tar` archive. So it does not contain individually "compressed" files.

You could just list, with `tar -tjf foo.tar.bz2`, that [decompressed] achive. If that command succeeds, the decompression of the entire `foo.tar.bz2` did work.

If you want to compress individual files in an archive, use some other tool, like [afio](http://members.chello.nl/~k.holtman/afio.html)

If you want to measure the total size of the decompressed archive (which is a good overestimate of the *cumulated* size of all the archived files), try

```
  bunzip2 < foo.tar.bz2 | wc
```